# Create unique plus random alphanumeric string

Tags: php

in a simple user table while adding users, the primary key "userid" field is automatically unique since it increments automatically. But I want to add another alphanumeric field of maximum length of 8 char which will be unique for each user. The following is the function I used. I got it from a website.

```
function unique_code($limit)
{
 return substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, $limit);
 }
 echo unique_code(8);
```

Will it always give me unique value? If yes, then it's okay. But if no, is there any other way?

Comment: *Will it always give me unique value?* no. why because it includes sha1 and then substr of only 8 chars. Some may collide because first 8 chars are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#120123) , uniqid() can create the same id many times:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
    echo uniqid(), PHP_EOL;
}

/** Example of Output:

5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c0ce
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6
5819f3ad1c4b6 */
```

i suggest to use the function that he created instead of using uniqid().

```
<?php
function uniqidReal($lenght = 13) {
    // uniqid gives 13 chars, but you could adjust it to your needs.
    if (function_exists("random_bytes")) {
        $bytes = random_bytes(ceil($lenght / 2));
    } elseif (function_exists("openssl_random_pseudo_bytes")) {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(ceil($lenght / 2));
    } else {
        throw new Exception("no cryptographically secure random function available");
    }
    return substr(bin2hex($bytes), 0, $lenght);
}
```

Comment: uniqid has a more entropy option: https://3v4l.org/iHMO6 also if done in a loop like your example then one would use the unique iteration number to add additional entropy https://3v4l.org/sYan5